# Execute multiple commands sequentially in terminal using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, gnome-terminal

I would like to do the following:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Change to the directory where target script resides.
3. Open the text file which provides the input to the target script. Hold/wait until the user has saved and closed the text file.
4. Execute the target script.

I wrote the following script to do the above:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "hello"
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "cd ~/automation/DVF99_Automation/Scripts;pwd;gedit sample.txt;python test.py;exec $SHELL"
echo "good bye"
```

The above gives me the following output:

```
user4@user-pc-4:~/Desktop$ ./DAT_run.sh
hello
good bye
```

And on the new gnome-terminal opened, I see the following message:

```
/home/user4/Scripts
From python script
From python script
From python script
From python script
From python script
```

The above means it has executed the python code and my requirements 1,2 and 4 have been met (not the 3rd). I'm unable to hold the `gedit` window as a foreground process until it has been saved and closed (so that the next statement is executed only after I close the file opened in `gedit`).

What could be going wrong here? I am new to shell scripting and feel like I could very well be missing something here. How can I achieve all my above requirements?

Comment: Could it be that the `gedit` being executed is a shell script which starts gedit in the background?

Comment: Nope. The `sample.txt` is just a plain text file.

Comment: I didn't refer to `sample.txt`. I refered to `gedit`. You could add before invoking gedit the two commands `type gedit; file $(type -p gedit)` .

Comment: I think you want `gedit -w sample.txt` to block until you exit the editor.

Answer (score -1):

btw, you need start the gedit in background.

Example:

```
$ gedit sample.txt&;python test.py;exec $SHELL"
```

Even more better is variable subsitution.

```
 #!/she/bang
 FILE=sample.txt
 gedit $(FILE)&;python test.py;exec $SHELL"
```

Comment: I would like to have `gedit` running as a foreground process and the remaining statement(s) executing only after I (save and) close the `gedit` window. Aplologize for missing this out. Have updated the post with this detail.

Comment: instead you can use touch.txt, if you want to create only the file. You can just copy paste the entire command from your script on terminal and see what's happening there.

Comment: I am not just trying to create a file. I'm prompting the user to enter/update a value inside it and save it so that my python program can read the updated file and do stuffs.

Comment: In that case your script run as cron job, at some scenario it prompts gedit ask user to enter the logs? In that case you have to wait till the gedit is closed. For that you can use trap signal to identify and once gedit is closed you can perform other command

Comment: [Quote file name variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) and [use lower case for your private variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: This attempts to run `FILE` as a command. You probably meant `"${FILE}"`, though the curly braces are completely optional here.